# How to fix 'Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context' error in R function

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I am trying to write my first function using `rlang` and I am having some trouble fixing the following error.

I've read the [vignette](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org), but didn't see a good example of what I'm trying to do.

```r
library(babynames)
library(tidyverse)

name_graph <- function(data, name, sex){
name <- enquo(name)
sex <- enquo(sex)

data %>%
  filter_(name == !!name, sex == !!sex) %>%
  select(year, prop) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(year, prop))
}

name_graph(babynames, Robert, M)
```

I'm expecting my distribution graph, but getting an error:

> Called from: abort(paste_line("Quosures can only be unquoted within a 
>   quasiquotation context.", 
>      "", "  # Bad:", "  list(!!myquosure)", 
>      "", "  # Good:", "  dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)"))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can modify the function by converting the quosures (`enquo`) to string in the `filter`

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
name_graph <- function(data, name, sex){
   name <- enquo(name)
   sex <- enquo(sex)

    data %>%
      filter(name == !! as_label(name), sex == !! as_label(sex)) %>%
      select(year, prop) %>%
      ggplot()+
              geom_line(mapping = aes(year, prop))
    }

name_graph(babynames, Robert, M)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the function `filter_`is deprecated and you should try avoid using it.
Also `dplyr::filter` doesn't work well if the variable name is the same as the input.

Try this:

```
name_graph <- function(data, myname, mysex){

data %>%
  filter(name == myname, sex == mysex) %>%
  select(year, prop) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(year, prop))
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, quosures are used if you try passing column names as input arguments. In your case you are passing character strings as inputs so you do not need quosures and it's better not to use them in your case.

Comment: You should point out that they don't seem to need quosures here, since they're not passing in a variable name

Comment: @Cettt
`Error in ~name == myname : object 'Chris' not found
Called from: ~name == myname
attr(,"class")
[1] "quosure" "formula"
attr(,".Environment")
<environment: 0x00000000124ce850>`
That's what I got with your code.

Comment: you have to call the function like this:
`name_graph(babynames, "Robert", "M")`